# Choosing what part of an image to display in a container smaller than the image size

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out how to choose the bottom part of the image that I'm using on the homepage of my website.

Its automatically starting from the top down but I want to choose what part to see, which would be lower down on the image.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Stylesheet.css">
<title>Kilbride Classic Cuisine</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="toplocation">
  <i class="fa fa-fax"></i> (01)-8393790&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
  <i class="fa fa-map-marker">&nbsp Unit 10,11,12, Baldoyle Industrial       Estate, Dublin 13, Ireland</a></i>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="menu">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#OurProducts">Our Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="#OurBrands">Our Brands</a></li>
      <li><a href="Aboutpage.php">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="imgwrap">
  <div id="img1">

  </div>
  </div>
```

css

```
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: sans-serif, arial;
}

#toplocation {
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
  color: White;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 100px;
}

.container-fluid {
  background-color: #fb0e3d;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}


/*.column{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:#b93333;
}*/

#menu {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: 1 solid #ccc;
  border-left: 1 solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1 solid #000000;
}

#menu li {
  float: left;
  background-color: #fb0e3d;
}

#menu li a {
  display: block;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0pxpx;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0pxpx;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 120px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#menu li a:hover {
  color: #fb0e3d;
  background-color: #fff;
}

div.imgwrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  max-width: MaxSize;
  max-height: MaxSize;
  border: 3px solid #4d4d4d;
  background-image: url('quiche.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

#contact {
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fb0e3d;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#imgcontainer {
  width: 80%;
  height: 30%;
  align: center;
}

#info {
  margin-left: 50px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#map {
  align: right;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include *only* the code that is relevant to your problem.

Comment: We would better understand the problem if you post your code along with image, probably a jsfiddle

Comment: @geeksal, how do I do that

Comment: go to jsfiddle.net and you will understand........

Comment: You're looking for `background-position`.

Comment: You could use `background-position: bottom`, or by using percentage values to pan your background image so the desired part is visible.

Comment: Thanks guys, that got it. For some reason the border on the right side won't work though. I have it as a full border, but it only covers 3 sides now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `background-position` property at the link below.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

This will allow you to specify where you want the image to start. For example, you may specify `background-position: center bottom;` to show the lower central part of the image. Alternatively you can specify absolute values in pixels.